# Navigation in Bottom Navigaiton View creates/destroys the fragment Navigation 2.4.2

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation, bottomnavigationview, back-stack

I am using the latest Navigation version 2.4.2.

I set up the bottom nav bar with the Navigation component as follow, the same way recommended by google:

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)

    val navView: BottomNavigationView = binding.navView

    val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment_activity_main)
    // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
    // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
    val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(
        setOf(
            R.id.navigation_home, R.id.navigation_dashboard, R.id.navigation_notifications
        )
    )
    setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
    navView.setupWithNavController(navController)
}
```

My menu:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item
    android:id="@+id/navigation_home"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_home_black_24dp"
    android:title="@string/title_home" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/navigation_dashboard"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_dashboard_black_24dp"
    android:title="@string/title_dashboard"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/navigation_notifications"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_notifications_black_24dp"
    android:title="@string/title_notifications" />
```

However, when I navigate from one fragment to the other, its onDestroy() is called and when I navigate back to it is recreated.

This is the case for all the fragment in the BottomNavView except the startDestination. The onCreate() for the startDestination is called only once and when navigating away from it, only the onDestroyView() is called. I want this behavior for all the other fragments as well as I need to put code in the onCreate() method and want it to run once once per lifecycle of the app.

Support for multiple backstack arrive with Navigation 2.4.0 so I don't know what's wrong. when calling findNavController.navigate(...), the previous fragment is kept in the backstack and is not destroyed(), and as far as I know the BottomNavBar calls the same method so I can't figure out why each fragment is being created/destroyed upon each navigation.

Me navigating from : Start Fragment -> Dashboard Fragment -> Navigation Fragment -> Start Fragment

[image]

All the fragment except the Start Fragment is recreated.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: When defining actions, you need to mention whether you want to restoreState or not. Try this in your action tag ==> app:restoreState="true"

Comment: @DaniyalJavaid Could you please to clarify more ?
Above code is just the menu item id, there is no action in this case. How to fix it ?

Comment: Any update on this @ThânHoàng.  We can only add app:restoreState="true"  to action inside the xml. But for menu we are only matching the id in the menu to the id we used to create <navigation id>. In the NavigationUI class, I see 
val builder = NavOptions.Builder().setLaunchSingleTop(true).setRestoreState(true)
when menuItem is clicked. Looking for a solution for. Creating a entire fragment seems redundant I'm not sure why they choose this path.
Also the AdvancedNavigationSample, also produces the same result

Comment: @BagadeshkumarR No update. I have move on ViewPager instead

Comment: Complete rubbish why would they not build it such that we could retain fragments in memory, similar to a pager, after all there are only max 5 fragments (for 5 tabs). Spent several days implementing this but wish I'd stuck with good old Activity based stacks!
I'm also seeing the viewmodel getting cleared (strangely only for the nav graph start destinations, not for fragments below that) - so I can't even hold state in the viewModel.  The only solution was to scope the startDestination fragment viewModels to the activity....

Answer (score 1):

For anyone looking for an answer to this question. Google replied that it is expected behaviour.

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/190893266

Comment: Similar reply (from Google?) on https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/issues/749